# Does soaking liver in water instead of milk work well?

Tags: meat, milk, water, soaking, liver

I researched and found that milk reduces the absorption of iron in your body. I have low iron and was wondering if I can soak liver in water instead of milk.

**Is it possible to soak liver in water instead of milk, as is usually recommended?**

Comment: Yes, see accepted answer [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41436/how-does-soaking-liver-in-milk-work).